# How to make sure the beginning of two strings match until the last word(s)?

Tags: python

So I have two strings:

```
failure = ""
success = "Today's day is Wednesday"
```

The `failure` string is an empty string but must end up to be exactly identical to the success string (for comparison reasons later down). The tricky part is, you can't just set them equal to each other and the `success` strings ends differently depending on the day. So while the `success` string changes, the `failure` string might not change (when it should).

Ultimately, the goal is the compare the two strings and make sure they are always equal no matter what day it is:

```
if (failure == success):
```

How do I make sure that the beginning of both the `failure` string and the `success` string matches word for word until the last word (which would be the day)? I thought about making a variable that we pass-in for the day. Something like `day_name` and use subtext but not sure how to execute that

Comment: Remove the last word from `success` and assign the result to `failure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last word from `success` and assign to `failure`:

```
import re

success = "Today's day is Wednesday";
failure = re.sub(r'\w+$', '', success)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `failure` to be the same as `success`, just do:

```
failure = success
```

this will change failure to be the same as succes. You can also check if failure is not the same as succes:

```
if failure != success:
    failure = success #change failure into success.
```

If you want to get the current day, you could use:

```
from datetime import date
import calendar
curr_date = date.today()
success = (f"Today's day is {calendar.day_name[curr_date.weekday()]}")
```